# Cocos2d-x v3.6 android черный экран при добавлении спрайтов

Tags: c++, android, cocos2d

Использую Cocos2d-x версии 3.6 для написания игры под Android. Тестирую на Samsung Galaxy S4 Mini с версией Android 4.4.2.

Игра состоит из двух сцен - главного меню и, собственно, самой игры.
В игре в init() загружается и отрисовывается Tilemap из двух видимых слоев. Так же в init() добавляется спрайт игрока. В отдельном Layer-е находится меню (одна единственная кнопка-картинка, которая возвращает на сцену с главным меню). Код отрисовки прикладываю ниже.

Теперь сама проблема. В update() сцены (вызывается из-за scheduleUpdate()) создается спрайт (еда), если количество еды на карте меньше MAX_FOOD. При добавлении этих спрайтов на сцену, сцена может в любой момент перестать отображать что-либо, кроме кнопки возврата в главное меню. Полностью черный экран с кнопкой возврата, исчезли добавленные спрайты еды, спрайт игрока и фоновая Tilemap. Это обычно случается через долю секунды, после запуска сцены: все отрисовывается и через долю секунды исчезает в черном экране. Иногда, такой "вылет" происходит через секунд пять-десять после запуска сцены. Причем кнопка возврата исправно отображается и работает. Если этого не произошло в первые пятнадцать секунд, то дальше такой проблемы не возникает.

Чем больше MAX_FOOD, тем с большей вероятностью при запуске сцены она станет черной. При значении 5, где-то каждый пятый запуск заканчивается черным экраном, при значении 10 - каждый пятый отображается нормально, а остальные четыре черные. LogCat на данную проблему никак не реагирует.

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным? В чем может быть проблема, какие пути ее решения?

Нарезка кода, отвечающие за рисование:

```
//Отображение Tilemap (в GameScene::init())
std::string file = "big_map.tmx";
auto str = String::createWithContentsOfFile (FileUtils::getInstance()->fullPathForFilename(file.c_str()).c_str());
_tileMap = TMXTiledMap::createWithXML(str->getCString(),"");
_background1 = _tileMap->getLayer("Layer1");
_background2 = _tileMap->getLayer("Layer2");
_impassableZones = _tileMap->getLayer("Impassable");
addChild(_background1, -1);
addChild(_background2, 1);
addChild(_impassableZones, 2);
_impassableZones->setVisible(false);

//Отображение игрока (в GameScene::init())
playerSprite = cocos2d::Sprite::create("player.png");
playerSprite->setPosition(x + _tileMap->getTileSize().width / 2, y + _tileMap->getTileSize().height / 2);
addChild(playerSprite, 0);

//Отображение кнопки возврата (в GameScene::init())
userInterface = Layer::create();
auto closeItem = MenuItemImage::create("button_pause1.png", "button_pause.png", CC_CALLBACK_1(GameScene::GoBack, this));
closeItem->setPosition(Point(closeItem->getContentSize().width/2 , visibleSize.height - closeItem->getContentSize().height/2));
auto menu = Menu::create(closeItem, NULL);
menu->setPosition(Point(0, 0));
userInterface->addChild(menu);
addChild(userInterface, 100);

//Вызывается каждый кадр
void GameScene::update(float dt){
    if((int)floatingFood.size() < MAX_FOOD){
        int dist = Helper::hypotenuse(visibleSize.width, visibleSize.height);
        //generateFood(playerSprite->getPosition(), dist, dist*2);
        generateFood(playerSprite->getPosition(), 0, 300); //Генерация еды
    }
    freeFood(playerSprite->getPosition());  //Удаление спрайтов еды, которая далеко
    floating();
    this->setViewPointCenter(playerSprite->getPosition());
}

//Создание спрайта еды в некоторой зоне вокруг игрока
void GameScene::generateFood(cocos2d::Point position, int min, int max){
    int distance = rand()%(max - min) + min;
    double angle = rand()%360;
    angle *= 3.14/180;
    Point pos = Point(distance*cos(angle), distance*sin(angle));
    Food* _food = new Food();
    Sprite* temp = Sprite::create("food1.png");
    _food->setSprite(temp);
    temp->setPosition(pos + position);
    addChild(temp, 10);
    floatingFood.push_back(_food);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в том, что  я создавал отдельные слои и добавлял на сцену, а саму карту тайлов не добавлял. В итоге, кокос ее удалил за ненадобностью, но в другой функции я обращался к ней, чтобы узнать координаты. Как следствие, они оказывались некорректными и эта функция помещала центр экрана на них. Но там ничего не было, поэтому рисовался черный экран.